# "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type" while passing model to a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have a view renders another partial view along the way. My view receives the model below

```
 public class JobsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<JobPost> JobPosts { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public SearchTerms searchTerms { get; set; }
    }
```

my Partial view receives the model SearchTerms below.

```
  public class SearchTerms
    {
        public string searchText { get; set; }
        public string JobFunction { get; set; }
        public string JobIndustry { get; set; }
        public string jobType { get; set; }
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }
        public string PostedDate { get; set; }
        public decimal MinSalary { get; set; }
    }
```

SearchTerms already part of JobsListViewModel .Therefore i tried to render my Partial view like below.

```
@Html.Partial("_SearchFormPartial",Model.searchTerms)
```

The above throws an error that

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'JobWebSite.WebUI.Models.JobsListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'JobWebSite.WebUI.Models.SearchTerms' "

From my partial above, i am passing Model.SearchTerms. Shouldnt that satisfy the requirement  ? Please any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Thank you for your responses. What Mr Stephen mentioned below happened to be the problem. Below is my Controller previously.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
     {
     JobPosts = (IEnumerable<JobPost>)
                          (from posts in repository.JobPosts
                           orderby posts.PostDate descending
                           select new
                           {
                               Id = posts.Id,
                               Post = posts.Post,
                               Logo = posts.Logo,
                               PostDate = posts.PostDate,
                               EmployerId = posts.EmployerId,
                               CategoryId = posts.CategoryId,
                               RegionId = posts.RegionId,
                               TypeId = posts.TypeId,
                               PostTitle = posts.PostTitle,
                               JobIndustryId = posts.JobIndustryId,
                               JobFunctionId = posts.JobFunctionId,
                               JobLevelId = posts.JobLevelId,
                               Salary = posts.Salary
                           }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new JobPost
                               {
                                   Id = x.Id,
                                   Post = x.Post,
                                   Logo = x.Logo,
                                   PostDate = x.PostDate,
                                   EmployerId = x.EmployerId,
                                   CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                                   RegionId = x.RegionId,
                                   TypeId = x.TypeId,
                                   PostTitle = x.PostTitle,
                                   JobIndustryId = x.JobIndustryId,
                                   JobFunctionId = x.JobFunctionId,
                                   JobLevelId = x.JobLevelId,
                                   Salary = x.Salary
                               })
                               .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                               .Take(PageSize),
                    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                    {
                        CurrentPage = page,
                        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                        TotalItems = repository.JobPosts.Count()
                    },
                    searchTerms = CtrlsearchTerms 


                };


     return View("Search", model);
    }
```

Note.  CtrlsearchTerms is set in the httpPost method. According to Mr Stephen , My SearchTerms was empty and that sure was the case. when i changed my Controller to

```
[HttpGet]
        public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
         {
         JobPosts = (IEnumerable<JobPost>)
                              (from posts in repository.JobPosts
                               orderby posts.PostDate descending
                               select new
                               {
                                   Id = posts.Id,
                                   Post = posts.Post,
                                   Logo = posts.Logo,
                                   PostDate = posts.PostDate,
                                   EmployerId = posts.EmployerId,
                                   CategoryId = posts.CategoryId,
                                   RegionId = posts.RegionId,
                                   TypeId = posts.TypeId,
                                   PostTitle = posts.PostTitle,
                                   JobIndustryId = posts.JobIndustryId,
                                   JobFunctionId = posts.JobFunctionId,
                                   JobLevelId = posts.JobLevelId,
                                   Salary = posts.Salary
                               }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new JobPost
                                   {
                                       Id = x.Id,
                                       Post = x.Post,
                                       Logo = x.Logo,
                                       PostDate = x.PostDate,
                                       EmployerId = x.EmployerId,
                                       CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                                       RegionId = x.RegionId,
                                       TypeId = x.TypeId,
                                       PostTitle = x.PostTitle,
                                       JobIndustryId = x.JobIndustryId,
                                       JobFunctionId = x.JobFunctionId,
                                       JobLevelId = x.JobLevelId,
                                       Salary = x.Salary
                                   })
                                   .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                                   .Take(PageSize),
                        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                        {
                            CurrentPage = page,
                            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                            TotalItems = repository.JobPosts.Count()
                        },
                         //Initialize my SearchTerms Below as suggested
                        searchTerms = new SearchTerms()


                    };


         return View("Search", model);
        }
```

This works fine. The error is now gone. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Its because the property `searchTerms` is `null`. Make sure you initialize it (either in the controller or in a parameterless constructor for `JobsListViewModel`

Comment: @Stephen You are correct . Pls see my update and Post your answer. Will accept it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke   You are correct . Pls see my update and Post your answer. Will accept it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when the model you are passing to the partial is `null`. In effect your doing `@Html.Partial("_SearchFormPartial", null)` which is the same as `@Html.Partial("_SearchFormPartial")`, that is, the `ViewDaatDictionary` of the main view (`JobsListViewModel`) is being passed to the partial. Initialize a new instance of `SearchTerms` in the controller or in a parameterless constructor, for example

```
public class JobsListViewModel
{
    public JobsListViewModel()
    {
        searchTerms = new SearchTerms();
    }
    public IEnumerable<JobPost> JobPosts { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public SearchTerms searchTerms { get; set; }
}
```